# I am trying to publish the App into playstores but its giving me for violating our dangerous products policy

Tags: android, cordova, android-security

this the error mail getting from the Google and i am using the Android studio for the development of apps i am not able to understand why i am getting this error because there no violence of the google developer policy
[this is project struture i had copied the WWW folder from the Created android folder by cordova](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvZxX.png)
    Vulnerability   APK Version(s)
    Apache Cordova

```
The vulnerabilities were fixed in Apache Cordova v.3.5.1. For more information about the vulnerabilities, and for guidance on upgrading Apache Cordova, please see https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2014/08/04/android-351.html. For other technical questions about Apache Cordova, please post to Stack Overflow and use the tags "android-security" and "cordova."
```

Comment: Read this and check if you did anything wrong https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy.html

Comment: checked it i had not did anything wrong

Comment: Update your Cordova version

Comment: So what.
You have'n created your project with NodeJS cmd ?

Comment: you are using an old version of cordova that has a security bug, update to use the latest

Comment: how to update it?@jcesarmobile

Comment: i had updated cordova i am not able to implement that in the android studio in my project i had just copied file in the cordova into the project structure i had updated my post please check it frds help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace the WWW folder with your contain folder in it after updating the cordova which includes CSS,Image,Js files and the links of html in it.

Answer (score 1):

```
npm install -g cordova
cd my_project
cordova platform update android
```

Comment: where should i write that please tell me

Comment: but i am using andriod studio na

Comment: can u explain me how to use that please

Comment: Is same process android studio too na

Comment: i am getting Error:Current working Directory is not a Cordova-based project

Comment: You have very basic knowledge of pg using Node.

Please Go through it... 

http://www.lynda.com/Nodejs-tutorials/Building-Mobile-Apps-PhoneGap-Command-Line-Interface/170057-2.html

Comment: you'd better explain why he has to do that

Comment: i had created the folder of cordova and platform android how can i add it in the my android studio

Comment: YourProject -> platforms -> android. 

Now put this android folder path and import it to Android Studio or eclipse

Comment: i must copy the www folder to that location na thats it?

Comment: No your www folder is exist in assets folder in YourProject -> platforms -> android 
Do all changes in This www folder.

Comment: Here is complete Example. 
Hope it will help you

http://www.pycode.com/android/creating-a-phonegap-cordova-3.0-app-in-eclipse.html

Comment: i had updated cordova i am not able to implement that in the android studio in my project i had just copied file in the cordova into the project structure i had updated my post please check it frds help me